# onClick и onLongClick срабатывает одновременно

Tags: android, recyclerview, onclicklistener

Есть `recyclerView`, на который установил `onClick(AlertDialog)` и `onLongClick(ContextMenu)`. Если удерживать определенное время, то срабатывает оба метода, но `alertDialog` перекрывает `contextMenu`. В чем может быть дело?

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(),
        recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        ViewGroup viewGroupRecycle = findViewById(R.id.layoutParent);
        View viewUpdate = getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.create, viewGroupRecycle);

        final EditText text = viewUpdate.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        builder.setView(viewUpdate);
        builder.setTitle(note_update);

        final int id = notesList.get(position).getId();
        String textStr = notesList.get(position).getText();

        text.setText(textStr);
        text.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) MainActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                assert keyboard != null;
                keyboard.showSoftInput(text, 0);
            }
        }, 50);

        builder.setPositiveButton(save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton(cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String strText = removeSeparator(text);
                Boolean check = checked(strText);

                if (check){
                    updatable(strText, id);
                    prepareData();
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                } else
                    message(error);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
    }
}));

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, final View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.add(0, R.id.move, 0, R.string.move_widget);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    try {
        int position = ((NotesAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter()).getPosition();

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.move:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WriteNotes.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", position);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

RecycleTouchListener

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private ClickListener clickListener;

public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}
}
```

Click установлен в Holder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NotesHolder holder, int position) {
    Notes notes = notesList.get(position);
    holder.tvText.setText(notes.getText());
    holder.tvDate.setText(notes.getDate());

    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            setPosition(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Реализацию RecyclerTouchListener пожалуйста

Comment: Скорее всего при LongClick возвращаете из него false, а нужно true, это значит что клик обработан, а так уходит дальше